# /etc/environment: line 2: PATH: No such file or directory

Tags: software-center, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. Recently I've noticed that Ubuntu Software Centre fails to install/remove packages to/from my computer.

Here is the error description.

```
installArchives() failed: Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-8ubuntu2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/jre/bin: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
Error in function: 
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-8ubuntu2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/jre/bin: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Following is the image for same:

[image: USC Error]

What is the reason for this and how can I fix this?

Output of `cat /etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
CLASSPATH= "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386/jre/bin"
```

Comment: Have you installed java 7? or did you removed java 7 directory without unstalling it? Seems like the error occurs while upgrading "install-info" package. try removing it first.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/environment` run from the terminal in your question. Don't delete it - it's needed to set some paths in your environment! It appears that this file is corrupted or contains invalid content. By posting the contents I may be able to provide you instruction on how to get it sorted.

Comment: @gertvdijk, I added the output of cat /etc/environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a fix.

My `/etc/environment` had the CLASSPATH variable set to my previous openJDK installation. Recently I installed Oracle JDK manually and removed openJDK. But somehow `/etc/environment` contained the old CLASSPATH value.

But what wonders me is that the issue appeared just recently that I could install/remove packages successfully even after my java re-installation.

Thanks @gertvdijk for your insight. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem, because in the back = number of more than one space, as follows:

```
PATH= "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin"
```

modify to this follow, it's ok.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin"
```

Answer (score -4):

Did you try the following??

1. Usually, interrupted software installations leave cyclic dependency issues. Try running the following commands.

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a    
   sudo apt-get clean    
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. You may have inadvertently disrupted your environment variables. Try moving your `/etc/environment` file to a different location for a while (don't delete it, you might want it back there if this is not the issue). However, if this is a solution, delete the said file

Comment: Nooo... don't get `/etc/envrionment` deleted or moved! It sets up the system paths like `/usr/bin` so your shell will find the commands.

Comment: @Damith, I think the problem is with my CLASSPATH value.